# Compound trigger, valor a não funcionar SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldeveloper

Tenho uma tabela Convocatoria(Hora, DataJogo, EquipaID, NIF, MinutosJogados) onde minutos jogados são normalmente 90.
No entanto, temos uma tabela Acao(Hora, DataJogo, EquipaID, NIF, Minuto, TipoAcaoID) E o problema é, se um jogador tem um cartão vermelho (TipoAcaoID = 8, por exemplo) ou dois cartoes amarelos  no minuto 32, a tabela convocatória devia mudar os minutos jogados para 32.
O trigger que fiz funciona para os cartões vermelhos, mas não consigo perceber porque é que não funciona para dois amarelos.
Trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_if_red_card_or_two_yellows_before_insert_new_summon
    FOR INSERT OR UPDATE ON ACOES
    COMPOUND TRIGGER
    ContagemAmarelosPKG INT := 0;
    ContagemVermelhosPKG INT := 0;

    BEFORE EACH ROW IS
    BEGIN
        IF :NEW.TipoAcaoID = 7 THEN
            ContagemAmarelosPKG := ContagemAmarelosPKG + 1;
        ELSIF :NEW.TipoAcaoID = 8 THEN
            ContagemVermelhosPKG := ContagemVermelhosPKG + 1;
        END IF;
    END BEFORE EACH ROW;

    AFTER STATEMENT IS
    BEGIN
        FOR c IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT NIF, DataJogo, Hora
            FROM Acoes
            WHERE (TipoAcaoID = 7 AND ContagemAmarelosPKG = 2)
                  OR (TipoAcaoID = 8 AND ContagemVermelhosPKG = 1)
        )
        LOOP
            IF ContagemAmarelosPKG = 2 THEN
                UPDATE Convocatoria
                SET MinutosJogados = (
                    SELECT Minuto
                    FROM Acoes
                    WHERE NIF = c.NIF AND DataJogo = c.DataJogo AND Hora = c.Hora AND TipoAcaoID = 7
                )
                WHERE NIF = c.NIF AND DataJogo = c.DataJogo AND Hora = c.Hora;
                
            ELSIF ContagemVermelhosPKG = 1 THEN
                UPDATE Convocatoria
                SET MinutosJogados = (
                    SELECT Minuto
                    FROM Acoes
                    WHERE NIF = c.NIF AND DataJogo = c.DataJogo AND Hora = c.Hora AND TipoAcaoID = 8
                )
                WHERE NIF = c.NIF AND DataJogo = c.DataJogo AND Hora = c.Hora;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;

        -- Reset the count values for the next trigger invocation
        ContagemAmarelosPKG := 0;
        ContagemVermelhosPKG := 0;
    END AFTER STATEMENT;
END check_if_red_card_or_two_yellows_before_insert_new_summon;
/
```

Comment: `IF :NEW.TipoAcaoID = 7` aqui está apenas verificando o valor da ação para um determinado insert por exemplo. Isso quer dizer que, mesmo que já exista um cartão amarelo, vai sempre contar 1, seria preciso contar o número de cartões já existens (`SELECT COUNT`) e setar isso na variável "ContagemAmarelosPKG", e a seguir aplicar a lógica de somar mais um caso o tipo de cartão seja outro amarelo (`IF :NEW.TipoAcaoID = 7`). Isso funciona com o vermelho porque basta apenas um, ou teria o mesmo problema

Answer (score 0):

Você está usando variáveis ​​de pacote (`PKGYellowCount` e `PKGRedCount`) que retêm seus valores entre as execuções do acionador.

Uma abordagem melhor seria usar uma tabela temporária para contar os cartões amarelos e vermelhos por jogador.

Por exemplo, este código:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_if_red_card_or_two_yellows_before_insert_new_summon
    FOR INSERT OR UPDATE ON ACOES
    COMPOUND TRIGGER

    Temp_Counts TABLE (
        NIF            NUMBER,
        ContagemAmarelos    NUMBER := 0,
        ContagemVermelhos NUMBER := 0
    );

    BEFORE EACH ROW IS
    BEGIN

        IF :NEW.TipoAcaoID = 7 THEN
            FOR rec IN Temp_Counts.FIRST..Temp_Counts.LAST LOOP
                IF Temp_Counts(rec).NIF = :NEW.NIF THEN
                    Temp_Counts(rec).ContagemAmarelos := Temp_Counts(rec).ContagemAmarelos + 1;
                    EXIT;
                END IF;
            END LOOP;
        ELSIF :NEW.TipoAcaoID = 8 THEN
            FOR rec IN Temp_Counts.FIRST..Temp_Counts.LAST LOOP
                IF Temp_Counts(rec).NIF = :NEW.NIF THEN
                    Temp_Counts(rec).ContagemVermelhos := Temp_Counts(rec).ContagemVermelhos + 1;
                    EXIT;
                END IF;
            END LOOP;
        END IF;
    END BEFORE EACH ROW;

    AFTER STATEMENT IS
    BEGIN

        FOR rec IN Temp_Counts.FIRST..Temp_Counts.LAST LOOP
            IF Temp_Counts(rec).ContagemAmarelos = 2 THEN
                UPDATE Convocatoria
                SET MinutosJogados = (
                    SELECT Minuto
                    FROM Acoes
                    WHERE NIF = Temp_Counts(rec).NIF AND TipoAcaoID = 7
                    ORDER BY Minuto
                    FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
                )
                WHERE NIF = Temp_Counts(rec).NIF;
            ELSIF Temp_Counts(rec).ContagemVermelhos = 1 THEN
                UPDATE Convocatoria
                SET MinutosJogados = (
                    SELECT Minuto
                    FROM Acoes
                    WHERE NIF = Temp_Counts(rec).NIF AND TipoAcaoID = 8
                    ORDER BY Minuto
                    FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
                )
                WHERE NIF = Temp_Counts(rec).NIF;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;

        -- limpa a tabela temporária
        Temp_Counts.DELETE;
    END AFTER STATEMENT;
END check_if_red_card_or_two_yellows_before_insert_new_summon;
/
```